# How to integrate a Django app with multiple forms in Django CMS as plugin?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-cms

I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/plugins.html) to integrate my Django app into my Django CMS website.

My app *Sale* has two models, `OrderModel()` and `CustomerModel()`, that both are used in `forms.py` to pass some fields to a form, like so:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerModel
        fields = ['firstname', 'surname', 'company', 'email',]

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderModel
        fields = ['product', 'delivery_date',]
```

As described in the tutorial, in `models.py` I generate the `SalePluginModel` and in `cms_plugins.py`, I specify the `SalePluginPublisher` plugin class, which is responsible for providing django CMS with the necessary information to render my app, like so in `models.py`:

```
class SalePluginModel(CMSPlugin):

    title = models.CharField(u'title',
        blank=True,
        help_text=u'Optional. Title of the widget.',
        max_length=64,
    )
```

and so in `cms_plugins.py`:

```
class SalePluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    model = SalePluginModel  # model where plugin data are saved
    module = _("Sale")
    name = _("Sale Plugin")  # name of the plugin in the interface
    render_template = "sale/sale_plugin.html"
    form = '' # How to pass multiple model forms here?
```

Now, the problem is, that only one form class can be passed to the `CMSPluginBase` as attribute. Is there a possibility to include both form classes in the `SalePluginPublisher` or in general, how can I integrate my app with two models and forms in the Django CMS?
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to clarify, you'd like to pass two forms to the plugin? If so, you can do the following:

```
class SalePluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    model = SalePluginModel  # model where plugin data are saved
    module = _("Sale")
    name = _("Sale Plugin")  # name of the plugin in the interface
    render_template = "sale/sale_plugin.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super().render(context, instance, placeholder)
        context['customer_form'] = CustomerForm()
        context['order_form'] = OrderForm()
        return context
```

You can handle the POST responses in the `render` function too if you don't have a dedicated POST url. You just need to access the request object, e.g. `self.request.POST`.

#### Edit:

The above works with Python 3, to use with Python 2 you need to change the first line of the render function to:

```
context = super(SalePluginPublisher, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, however I had to pass `SalePluginPublisher, self` to the `super()` function, so `context = super(SalePluginPublisher, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)`. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. My example works for Python 3, for Python 2 you need to do as you've said above. I should have specified :) I've edited the answer now.